# Multiple authentication per user with Friend in Clojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I'm trying to support users authenticating with multiple authentication providers.

Since Friend's `credential-fn` only cares about the user currently signing in, how do I handle an already signed in user authenticating with an additional OAuth provider, for example?